# Routing in OpenVPN server to LAN in private subnet

Tags: openvpn

I am new to networking and have an OpenVPN server running with tun interface on a headless Ubuntu Server 16.04 . I am trying to access my resources in my LAN remotely using the, openVPN service I have setup, in an office that is set behind another LAN which is the gateway to the WAN. So Router 1/Gateway has an address of 192.168.x.0

Router 2 which is the lead way to my private subnet is 192.168.x.1(All devices in this network have static IP's)

How do I configure my OpenVPN server to allow me to access my resources in the second LAN. I amnew to networking and have done alot of research, but feel like I'm missing some concepts that are disabling me from moving forward. I want to route instead of bridge like the OpenVPN website suggests for now. Do I configure the server.conf file on the server and if so how do route to the address specified above? Also do I do some port forwarding from router 1 to router 2 get the traffic over the VPN once enabled to route to my network. Right now my virtual machine network setting is on NAT and I would also like to know what is the best setting to accomplish my task. I have researched for about a week now and can't find anything clear enough to explain these concepts if someone could help please!

Answer (score 0):

To access my LAN from my VPN server I added this line to server.conf

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.2
```

192.168.1.2 is my server's static IP address from my router.  You may have to modify the addresses based on your setup.

Comment: How do I direct traffic to my LAN with the private subnet though do I do port forwarding from the router the is the gateway to the WAN?

Comment: how did you add this? it complains about the syntax

Comment: That's a direct, correct copy of the line out of my server.conf . apt-cache policy openvpn gives me 2.3.10-1ubuntu2.1, perhaps you are running a different version.